# Woocommerce: Change Cash on delivery to NO for Bundle products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to change the cash on delivery option for bundle products.
Whenever users creates a bundle on the website, it can contain both virtual and physical products. There is a default option in woocommerce to disable COD for Virtual product but for bundle products COD is still displayed.
In simple words, i would like to disable COD if there is any virtual product in the Cart.
Logic: Cart contains Virtual Product? Yes? Disable COD

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with that. Did you have a programming question? This site is for questions, not a place to dump your to-do/requirements list.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for solution. There exists a plugin that can solve this issue.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-cod-advanced/